# ZFS broken after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: 15.10, zfs

Upgraded earlier from 15.04 to 15.10, now my ZFS system won't mount. Checking for updates comes up with "Unable to locate package ubuntu-zfs" checking the PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=wily) it seems that the PPA for 15.10 is missing ubuntu-zfs.

Does anyone have a work around for getting my zpool to work again. I've tried using ZFS-Fuse but it's running an older version than when I was using ubuntu-zfs.

Any help in getting my ZFS system working again would be appreciated.

Comment: Cant you just reistall the 15.04 version ubuntu-zfs? Or did the 4.2 kernel cause that not to work now?

Comment: In my case the system has been upgraded multiple times, or at least from 14.04 and up. I booted with the live 15.10 USB and was able to install the zfsutils-Linux package and mount my drive no problem. Once I figure out how to purge all instances of zfs on my system I'll try installing again. And yes I have run apt-get update many times.

Comment: And there you go. After purging all zfs related packages (zfs-doc), I've finally been able to install zfsutils-linux.

Comment: I was able to install zfsutils-linux by installing a specific version of zfs-doc, it shows my zpool but never mounts, if I try mounting it manually it says can't mount a directory that isn't empty. Also on installing zfsutils-linux it says to install zfs-initramfs which doesn't seem to do anything other than upgrade zfs-doc past the part where it works with zfsutils-linux...

Comment: Guys, please don't get into an edit war for whether or not 16.04 should be added into the topic.  We do have 15.10 questions which solutions also work for 16.04 and others, it is not necessary to be overly specific and split hairs over something not being present in the title.  This post will automatically unlock in under a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who encounter the following errors,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
zfsutils-linux : ***Depends: zfs-doc (= 0.6.4.2-0ubuntu1) but 0.6.5.3-1~wily is to be installed***
                  Depends: libnvpair1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libuutil1linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzfs2linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libzpool2linux but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: zfs-dkms but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is most probably due to having `ppa:zfs-native/stable` in your apt source repository.  Remove the `ppa:zfs-native/stable` from your apt repository, and re-run `apt-get update`.  Then proceed to install via `apt-get install zfsutils-linux`

That should fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was my problem. To remove the repo: `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable`

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 15.10 has ZFS support out of the box. Try to install zfsutils-linux which builds the native kernel modules for Linux (zfs-dkms).

```
$ apt-get install zfsutils-linux
```

Comment: Yes, but still zpool won't mount after reboot.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well after an upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. I also got the unmet dependencies issue that TL-Aiyor and others listed. Removing the PPA did not work for me though. I had to purge all (probably could have just purged zfs-doc but just purged everything) zfs from the system and re-install.

```
apt-add-repository --remove ppa:zfs-native/stable
zpool export tank
apt-get purge zfs*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install zfsutils-linux
zpool import tank
```

Everything after that went just dandy.