# So many users on ZFS pool? Cannot kill them all :( Cannot export pool :(

Tags: mount, ssh, do-release-upgrade, zfs

Hoping someone can help me.

I am trying to export my ZFS pool so I can upgrade my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10.

I tried doing do-release-upgrade, and lost my pool, on discovering instructions, I have rolled back to backup and trying to export pool first.

However I am getting this error:

```
# sudo zpool export -f mynas
umount: /mynas: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
cannot unmount '/mynas': umount failed
```

So I tried using fuser, and I get a stack of user ids using the pool.

```
# sudo fuser -c /mynas
/mynas:               3519m  3521m  3535m  3560m  3562m  3565m  3566m  3567m  3568m  3569m  3571m  3582m  3670m  3715m  3719m  3727m  3737m  3754m  3755m  3759m  3794m  3796m  3798m  3858m  3859m  3912m  3945m  3947m
```

I tried killing them all, but it kills even my ssh session, and when I restart the session, I get a stack more ids'

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

[Edit]
Further to that I have tried killing id's using lsof /mynas to id proceces, all except ssh ids, but still get same error / fail message :(

```
# sudo lsof /mynas
COMMAND    PID  USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
sshd      3068  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sshd      3068  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
sshd      3139 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sshd      3139 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
bash      3140 craig mem    REG   0,23    20767 221270 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo
sudo      3154  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sudo      3154  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
sudo      3154  root mem    REG   0,23     1389 221380 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
sudo      3154  root mem    REG   0,23     1932 221427 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/sudoers.mo
sshd      3426  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sshd      3426  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
sshd      3430 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sshd      3430 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
sshd      3484 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sshd      3484 craig mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
bash      3485 craig mem    REG   0,23    20767 221270 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo
sudo      3499  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
sudo      3499  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
sudo      3499  root mem    REG   0,23     1389 221380 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo
sudo      3499  root mem    REG   0,23     1932 221427 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/sudoers.mo
bash      3501  root mem    REG   0,23     3094 221274 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
winbindd  3517  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
winbindd  3517  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
winbindd  3519  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
winbindd  3519  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
nmbd      3525  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204062 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/lowcase.dat
nmbd      3525  root mem    REG   0,23   131072 204063 /mynas/usr/share/samba/codepages/upcase.dat
NetworkMa 3528  root mem    REG   0,23     3094 221274 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
NetworkMa 3528  root mem    REG   0,23     1959 223721 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo
NetworkMa 3528  root mem    REG   0,23     2581 221373 /mynas/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/NetworkManager.mo
```

Comment: Perhaps if you are using ssh, your user is within list. Try to identify your UID and kill everybody except you. Be the last Prince of the Universe ;)

Comment: Thanks @Danatela, I have taken a look at my UID, but it doesn't appear to be using it at this time? '# fuser -c /mynas
/mynas:               3140m  3272m
# echo $UID
1000
# id
uid=1000(craig) gid=1000(craig) groups=1000(craig),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(sambashare),113(lpadmin)'

Comment: code format:
`# fuser -c /mynas
/mynas:               3140m  3272m
# echo $UID
1000
# id
uid=1000(craig) gid=1000(craig) groups=1000(craig),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(sambashare),113(lpadmin)`

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to this was to ignore the issue of umount of the zpool.

I just tried to do a zpool import on ubuntu 15.10 after install and it has worked :)

Now I have a fully working zfs zpool on my shiny new Ubuntu 15.10.

Thanks to @Danatela for comment.

If you, like I run into issues with ZFS on ubuntu 15.10, here is something I hope helps you.

1. You do not need to add the package/ ppa to 15.10, it is stock standard, just run `sudo apt-get zfs-utils-linux` (as per [ZFS broken after upgrading to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691576/zfs-broken-after-upgrading-to-15-10))
2. I then had to rebuild zfs as per the instructions here https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1155

Hope this helps someone on this path.